# How to disable Elevated Button Border

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

[image]

How to remove disable border side Elevated Button. Previously I used Flat Button. After I use the new SDK Version. There are some function buttons that I cannot use. Raised button and Flat button one of them.

Code:

```
ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 5, 30, 5),
                side: BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('Dashboard',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
              ),
              
            ),
```

Back to my question. Is there a way for me to disable the border side Elevated Button?

Answer (score 2):

**Two things to consider:**

1. `TextButton` is alternative to `FlatButton` in new docs.
2. In your code change elvation to `0` to make it work as `FlatButton`.

---

**Explanation:**

1. Apparently it is `elevation` which you have misunderstood as `border`.
   Try setting it to `0`.

Updated Code

```
           ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                elevation: 0, //  Add this
                // primary: Colors.white, Try avoiding this as it is deprecated
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 5, 30, 5),
                side: BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('Dashboard',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
              ),
            ),
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

---

2. Adding on further

[image]

Replacement of `Flat Button` is `Text Button`. For further details refer https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `elevation:0` to your button

```
ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            elevation: 0,
                            primary: Colors.white,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 5, 30, 5),
                            side: BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text('Dashboard',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                          ),
                 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want border or elevation, perhaps you should not use `ElevatedButton`, but instead a `TextButton`.

`TextButton` is the new `FlatButton`.

Check the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html) on TextButton.

Differences:

```
Row(
  children: [
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('TextButton'),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('ElevatedButton #1'),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('ElevatedButton #2'),
    )
  ],
),
```

Not pressing last button:

[image]

Pressing last button:

[image]